# pass array to function by reference

Tags: c++, arrays, reference

```
void printElements(int(arr)[4])   // option 1
//void printElements(int(&arr)[4])  // option 2
{
    int length( sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]) ); 
    std:: cout <<"length is "<< length << std::endl;
    for (int i( 0 ); i < length; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

with the main function

```
int main() {
    int arr[]{99, 20, 14, 80};
    printElements(arr);
}
```

As listed, two options: one is `void printElements(int(arr)[4])`, another is `void printElements(int(&arr)[4])`. But the first one will `cout` the size of the array is 2. The second says the size of the array is 4. Why is the difference?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/1782465

Comment: C-Arrays are really confusing, it you can, use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead

Comment: Passing `int(arr)[4]` is just syntax sugar for passing the array as an `int*`, as an array *decays* into a pointer to its first element, thus `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])` is the same as `sizeof(int*) / sizeof(int)`, which is 2 if `int*` is 4 bytes and `int` is 2 bytes (not many compilers use a 2-byte `int` nowadays, most have a 4-byte `int` instead). Passing `int (&arr)[4]` instead, there is no decay, thus `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])` is the same as `sizeof(int[4]) / sizeof(int)`, which is always 4.

Comment: This is sneaky behavior inherited from C. Arrays aren't passed by value to function arguments. `int(arr)[4]` is quietly replaced with `int * arr`. The size is not enforced.

Comment: This question is closed for the **wrong** reason. Saying the array decays to a pointer is only half the answer. You also need to explain the reference part.